# What does Adam Smith mean by equality of condition?

Tags: adam-smith

According to Chomsky, Adam Smith distingushes between equality of opportunity and equality of condition and that he supported the latter over the former.

Although I have come across the former term and have some appreciation of what it means, I have not come across the latter term. What does Adam Smith mean by it?

Answer (score 4):

The term "equality of condition" can also be thought of as "equality of outcome."

In this context, it refers to the idea that people in a society/state have approximately the same overall quality of life, regardless of opportunity, socioeconomic circumstances, prejudicial treatment, advantages/disadvantages, etc.

This is an oversimplification but, to put it another way, you could think of equality of ***opportunity*** (in regards to material wealth, access to luxuries, health and quality of life, etc.) as "equalizing how people start" and equality of ***condition*** as "equalizing how people finish."